# Is there a Gaussian-mixture process?

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, normal-distribution

Let $\Theta$ be an $\mathbb R^d$-valued Gaussian-mixture random variable with $k$ Gaussian components $\Phi_1,\Phi_2,\ldots,\Phi_k$, where $\Phi_i$ has mean vector $\mu_i$ and covariance matrix $\Sigma_i$, and mixing probabilities $p_1,p_2,\ldots,p_k$. Let $C$ be the conditioning categorical random variable. Then, $Y_x=\Theta^Tx$ is a random process indexed by $x\in\mathbb R^d$. For any $x\in\mathbb R^d$, the moment-generating function of $\Theta^Tx$ is

$$
\begin{aligned}
M_{\Theta^Tx}(t)=\mathbf E[e^{t\Theta^Tx}]=\mathbf E[\mathbf E[e^{t\Theta^Tx}|C]]=\sum_{i=1}^kp_iM_{\Phi_i^Tx}(t)
\end{aligned}
$$

Since linear transformations of Gaussian random variables are Gaussian, $\Phi_i^Tx$ has mean $\mu_i^Tx$ and variance $x^T\Sigma_ix$. Therefore, $\Theta^Tx$ is Gaussian-mixture with $k$ components, the $i$-th component having mean $\mu_i^Tx$ and variance $x^T\Sigma_ix$, and the same mixing probabilities $p_1,p_2,\ldots,p_k$.

Can $Y_x$ be called a Gaussian-mixture process or a mixture-Gaussian process or a mixture of Gaussian processes? Has this kind of random process been studied?

Comment: Well known: standard reference is the work of Brigo-Mercurio like [this](https://www.ma.imperial.ac.uk/~dbrigo/lognsmile.pdf).

Comment: @Snoop What is the proper name for that process? I see no mention of the name "Gaussian-mixture process" or anything similar in your reference, except "stock-price process", "CEV process", "diffusion process" and "lognormal process".

Comment: I suggest looking up the authors and their work such as [this other reference](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0812.4052.pdf), and reading carefully in the links I provided how they derive mixture processes for specific purposes.